# Trouble Obtaining Auth Token from Upwork API Python

Tags: python, callback, upwork-api

I have an Upwork API associated with my account, and I'm trying to use it for messaging purposes.  I am following the API reference documentation. I have both the consumer and secret keys.

However, I'm encountering an issue that I am making a call to the callback endpoint to receive the `auth_token` necessary to proceed further, but I am not receiving it as expected.

Could someone please help me identify and resolve this issue?

main.py

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import upwork

app = Flask(__name__)

config = upwork.Config({
    "consumer_key": "xxxxxxx",
    "consumer_secret": "xxxxxxx",
    "redirect_uri": "https://localhost"
})


@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    # Get the authorization code from the request
    auth_code = request.args.get('code')
    client = upwork.Client(config)
    token = client.get_authorization_url()
    # print("Authorization URL:", token)
    return f"Authorization URL:{token}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5000)
```

calling the callback as:

test.py

```py
import requests

response = requests.get("http://localhost:5000/callback")
```

getting this in return:

```
Authorization URL:https://www.upwork.com/services/api/auth?oauth_token=None
```

I am expecting it to return the `auth_token` so that I can proceed further with it.

Comment: Hi Brian
What version of python you use, i.e. what python upwork library do you use?
Were you able to execute the raw example from https://github.com/upwork/python-upwork-oauth2/blob/master/example/myapp.py ?

Comment: Hi @mnovozhylov, I am using Python 3.10 and I am using python-upwork-oauth2. I tried running above raw example but it is returning "Missing or invalid redirect_uri parameter value"

Comment: Muhammad, you need to specify `redirect_uri` in the config, like:
```
config = upwork.Config(
        {
            "client_id": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
            "client_secret": "bbbbbbbbbb",
            "redirect_uri": "https://test.com/callback",
        }
    )
```
If it's already specified, check the settings of your api key and make sure it's identical to what you specified in the `redirect_uri` configuration value.